# option on change, execute event javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my code, i have an option button collection as this. I want in my javascript file to execute a function when option is changed.

```
<div class="col-sm-8 user-type" >
  <%= f.collection_radio_buttons :team_account_type, [ ['admin', 'Administrator'], ['team_leader', 'Team Leader'], ['standard_user', 'Standard User']], :first, :last, checked: ['standard_user', 'Standard User']%>
</div>
```

my js file

```
 $('#team_account_type').on('change', function() {
        console.log("i have selected team leader")
 });
```

But it is not working. when i click on the different options, it doesnt catch it or recognize it. Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What does the generated HTML look like? Does the ID you are matching on get generated as you expect?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your code inside `$(function(){ ... });` so that change event handler applied on when DOM is ready.

```
$(function(){
    $("#team_account_type").on("change", function() {
        console.log("i have selected team leader");
    });
});
```

OR you can delegate the change event using `document` object

```
 $(document).on("change","#team_account_type", function() {
            console.log("i have selected team leader");
    });
```